# composer update openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS mamp PHP 8.1 error

Tags: php, composer-php, mamp

I'm migrating over to PHP 8.1 on my Windows 10 machine. I'm using the free version of MAMP 5.0.5, I had recently uninstalled MAMP 4. I'm now on PHP 8.1, and have updated both the System variables and User variables in the Environment Variables control panel:

User path: `C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0`
System path: `C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0`

I can verify that when I run `php -v` in my terminal, it points to MAMP, and the loaded config is the MAMP one, but when running `composer update` in my terminal of my project, it says the OpenSSL module isn't installed, but opening my `php.ini` I can see it's listed. Strangely though, running `php -m` it doesn't show up.

What am I missing?

[image]

extensions in ini file:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext\"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;
; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; Note that it should be the name of the module only; no directory information
; needs to go here.  Specify the location of the extension with the
; extension_dir directive above.


; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.

extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_gd.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_imagick.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_apc.dll
;extension=php_apcu.dll
;extension=php_eaccelerator.dll
;extension=php_xcache.dll
;zend_extension=php_opcache.dll

;extension=php_ftp.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_xdebug.dll
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of text, copy'n'paste the actual text instead! What happens when you run `php -i`, is OpenSSL mentioned in the results and how?

Comment: How is this problem related to Composer? What did you try to resolve it?